# still about python file operation

Tags: python, file-io

I'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.3.

```
PS C:\Python27\LearnPythonTheHardWay> python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input = open('file_operation_sample.txt', 'a+')
>>> print input.tell()  # first 'tell()'
0
>>> input.write(u'add')
>>> print input.tell()
12
>>> input.seek(0)
>>> print input.read()
123456789add
>>> input.close()
>>>
```

I'm so puzzled why the first `tell()` prints `0`(I thought it would output `9`)? 'a+' is an append mode, the file pointer should be at the EOF. And I'm more puzzled that finally the string 'abc' is appended to '123456789'?

another question,

```
PS C:\Python27\LearnPythonTheHardWay> python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from io import open
>>> input = open('file_operation_sample.txt', 'a+')
>>> print input.tell()
9
>>> input.write(u'add')
3L
>>> print input.tell()
12
>>> input.seek(2)
2
>>> input.seek(2, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks
>>>
```

what's the problem? if i comment out `from io import open`, it will be ok.

Comment: The last issue might be a bug, see http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/764284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of Python's `tell()` is the same as C's `ftell()`.  The [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) notes:

> Note that when a file is opened for appending data, the current file position is determined by the last I/O operation, not by where the next write would occur.

That would explain why your first tell is `0` - you haven't done any file I/O yet.

---

Here's an illustration. First we'll write 5 characters to the file.  As we expect, the write starts at `0` and the file pointer is at `5` when we're done.

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('12345')
    fh.tell()

5L
```

Now we open it for appending.  We start at `0` as you've found.  But now we do a `read()` from the file and not too surprisingly, we're reading starting at `0`.  After the read, the file pointer has moved to `5`.

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'a+') as fh:
    fh.tell()
    fh.read()
    fh.tell()

0L
'12345'
5L
```

Ok, so let's open the file for appending and do a write this time.  As the documentation states, before the write the file pointer is moved to the end of the file.  So we get our new bytes after the old ones, even though the file pointer was `0` before the write.

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'a+') as fh:
    fh.tell()
    fh.write('abc')
    fh.tell()
    fh.seek(0)
    fh.read()

0L
8L
'12345abc'
```

The documentation for Python's `seek()` also hints at this behavior:

> Note that if the file is opened for appending (mode 'a' or 'a+'), any
>   seek() operations will be undone at the next write.

Comment: then what does it mean:`(When a file is opened for appending, the file position is moved to end of file before any write operation.)` (words in the parentheses in the documentation page)?

Comment: @user1477871 it's moved to the end of file *just* before the write operation - meaning after you make the function call.  I will update my answer with some sample code.

Comment: i see, many thanks :], and if u add `from io import open` u will find something different.